# Content of my page overlaps the drop-down menu in IE7

Tags: css, internet-explorer-7

I've tried positioning the header 'relative' with a high z-index and the content with position relative as well but the drop down hides as soon as I mouse over above where the content starts in IE 7. It's on this page - http://www.legrandconfectionary.com/truffle-flavors/ I thought it has something to do with tool-tip on the truffles but it's happening on every page. Help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to go out on a limb and say it's related to your tooltip plugin's `div`s which are left behind after you've no longer hovered over them. You can't see them, but they are there. Try adding this to your CSS file:

```
.tooltip { z-index: 50; }
```

Theoretically this will prevent the tooltip from being rendered on top of the UL element making up the drop-down menu. I have a feeling that IE 7 is bubbling the `mouseover` event onto the hidden tooltip (which probably stops the bubbling at itself) thus cancelling the `mouseover` event on your UL. Which your nav relies on since IE7 doesn't support `:hover` on `LI` elements.

**EDIT:** After reviewing further I am no longer convinced that it is the `div` which is created by the tooltip plugin, but I am convinced that what I stated about the plugin cancelling the bubble on the `mouseover` event. I believe your tooltip plugin is the culprit. Try disabling it and then check if the behavior persists.